# TeamCity - using TFS changeset number inside ASP.NET site CI build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have configured a TeamCity project to retrieve bits from TFS and publish an ASP.NET web site. I'd like to display the number of the TFS changeset used by TeamCity in the footer of the generated website, like so: "MyWebSite v1.0.[changeset number]. Could you please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using `1.0.[changeset number]` number as the build number in TeamCity?

Comment: Yes. I use %build.counter%.%system.build.vcs.number%